# Android: Disabled preference with regular font colors

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I got a `PreferenceActivity` with a preference which is disabled by setting the `android:enabled="false"` in the xml. When doing so, the preference appear like disabled things do - with fade colors. Is there a way to display the disabled preference with regular string color like an enabled preference? Or maybe there's a way to just add a regular preference which is not disabled but somehow not editable and won't respond when clicked on?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried setting a style on the item? Such as `android:style="@android:style/TextAppearance"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting another property at the definition of the preference:

```
android:selectable="false"
```